# Jenkins get git URL for a job

Tags: json, api, jenkins

Is there a way to get a git URL for a job in json format?

I tried the job's API but does not include this info.
`http://jenkins:8080/view/job/jobname/api/json?pretty=true`

Thank you.

Edit: I want to get a "Repository URL"
[image]

Comment: Added a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins natively provides the job configuration (which includes the Git URL) in XML format via

```
http://jenkins:8080/job/jobname/config.xml
```

If you absolutely require JSON output from your HTTP request to Jenkins, then the  best option is probably to use the REST API to run a custom Groovy script that provides the required information in JSON format.

Comment: XML does not have git url too

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Git URL" -- could you share a screenshot please?

Comment: Added a screenshot

Comment: There was a typo in the URL (superfluous `view/`) that I copied from your original URL Please try again. The Git URL must exist in the XML data.